# Where does the CAShapeLayer do its drawing?

Tags: ios

When a path is set, draw(in: ctx) still isn't called despite having output. I originally went down the path of subclassing CAShapeLayer but now I'm just confused how CALayer works.

Comment: Calayer.setNeedDisplay to call the draw function after initial drawing.

Comment: No, the issue is that the path is drawn -- *without* a call to draw(in: ctx). I'm just trying to figure where the drawing for a CAShapeLayer occurs. Is it done through some private magic?

Comment: It’s probably cashapelayer override func display() with the content updating like path.